# Calling Scrapy Spider from Django

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have a project with a django and scrapy folder in the same workspace:

```
my_project/
    django_project/
        django_project/
            settings.py
        app1/
        app2/
        manage.py
        ...
    scrapy_project/
        scrapy_project/
            settings.py
        scrapy.cfg
        ...
```

I've already connected scrapy with my django app1 model so every time I run my spider, it stores the collected data in my postgresql db.
This is how my scrapy project can access to the django model

```
#in my_project/scrapy_project/scrapy_project/settings.py
import sys
import os
import django

sys.path.append('/../../django_project')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'django_project.settings'
django.setup()
```

Everything works great when I call the spider from the command line, but when I wanted to call the spider as a script from a django view or a Celery task in django, for example:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl('spider_name')
process.start()
```

I get an Error:

```
KeyError: 'Spider not found: spider_name'
```

I think I'm suppose to tell Django where is Scrapy located (as I've done in scrapy settings), but I don't know how.
To be honest, I'm not even sure that how I design my folder structure for this project is the correct choice.

Comment: I guess your `scrapy_project` is not in the `PATH`.

Comment: Is it enought that `scrapy_project` is on the `PATH`? I think that `scrapy_project` must be the current working directory (but I just briefly read the code).

Comment: I fixed the issue by putting a symlink to `scrapy.cfg` in `django_project/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

follow example from [scrapy doc](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script):

```py
from my_projec.scrapy_project.spiders import MySpider
...
process.crawl(MySpider)
```

Comment: This will import the file but not the class, you may want to do MySpider.SpiderClassName inside crawl statement.