# Spider not found: Django Scrapy integration

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I am trying to run a **Scrapy** spider inside my **Django** project's view.
This is my project structure.

```
ScrapyPro       .
    ├── ScrapyPro
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── items.py
    │   ├── pipelines.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   └── spiders
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       └── demo_spider.py
    └── scrapy.cfg
    │  
WebCrawlerPro   
    ├── WebCrawlerApp
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │
    ├── WebCrawlerPro
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   ├── wsgi.py
    │   ├── settings.py
    └── scrapy.cfg
```

Here, **ScrapyPro** is scrapy project and **WebCrawlerPro** is Django project.

And here is the view from where I am trying to run a spider:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import urllib
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

# Create your views here.
def home_crawl(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        keyword = request.POST.get("search")
        keyword = urllib.quote(keyword)
        url =( "https://some_example.com/q/%s" % keyword)
        crawler = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
        crawler.crawl('example', url=url)
        crawler.start()

    return render(request,'index.html',{"foo":"bar"})
```

But when I  POST a request through the form in this view.

This error appears :

```
KeyError at /
'Spider not found: example'
```

And when I manually run the spider from ScrapyPro project by :

```
scrapy crawl example
```

It executes successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you defined the `example` spider somewhere?

Comment: Yes, in the **demo_spider** file of ScrapyPro's spider folder and from there, it gets searched by **SPIDER_MODULES** setting of scrapy.

Comment: and you are sure that the name property matches `example`?

Comment: Yes @N.Ivanov , spiders have a filed "name" which is equal to **example** in my case.

Comment: This is not the right approach of doing things. You need to add scrapyd and configure scrapyd. Then from your Django code you should schedule the scraper and take the results from there

Comment: @TarunLalwani I will definitely use scrapyd then. Any idea about this error though?

Comment: Thats is a PythonPath issue, set the PYTHONPATH to `WebCrawlerPro` folder also and then try

Comment: The root folder of scrapy must be in the current working directory. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497944/calling-scrapy-spider-from-django#comment80677699_42497944